# Can't Access my web application from client machine and mobile

Tags: wampserver, codeigniter-3

I have built my web application using Code Igniter, version 3.0.3. The problem I face is that I can't access my application from a client machine or a smartphone. I have turned off my firewall, I have put my WAMP Server version 2.5 online, but it doesn't seem to work. The browser keeps saying that "The Site can't be reached". What should I do in order to make this work?

Comment: Move site to live and check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to visit your own site with other mobile devices, there conditions need to be satisfied:
1、Your own site need to be published on the Internet, but not just started on your own mainframe. Normally, you need mapping a public IP address to your own server.
2、If condition 1 will not be satisfied, this application can be visited within the same gateway or route. This means that you server and mobile devices should connect a same router.

Comment: I agree with you. I just want to do a simple test from my machine for presentation purposes.